# why the same functions with same querys gives a result while another not in sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3-python

I don't get it ....

i have a few functions that return rows from sqlite tables.
Problem is that some sql querys are working while another not.
Function that working perfect :

```
    def selectAll(predstavnik_id):
        q = "SELECT * FROM ulaz WHERE predstavnik_id = (?)"
        cursor.execute(q, str(predstavnik_id))
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        if rows is None:
            return None
        else:
            return rows
```

And the other one that don't return rows:

```
    def selectStanByUlaz(stan_id):
        q = "SELECT * FROM stan WHERE ulaz_id = (?)"
        cursor.execute(q, str(stan_id))
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        if rows is None:
            return None
        else:
            return rows
```

There is no any errors, just won't return rows !
I tried in sqlite studio with same query syntax and it's working just fine
What could be a problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those are not the same queries

Comment: Of course that are not the same queries. First one querying table "ulaz" and another one querying table "stan". But the principle are the same ...

Answer (score 2):

Both of these functions don't do what you expect them to do:

```
cursor.execute(q, str(predstavnik_id))
cursor.execute(q, str(stan_id))
```

The second argument to `cursor.execute` [is defined](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) to take a `sequence` of parameters.

Notice that `cursor.execute(q, str(predstavnik_id))` is **not** executing with `str(predstavnik_id)` being the only parameter: `cursor.execute` is defined to take a sequence, and `str(predstavnik_id)` is a sequence of characters. You probably meant `cursor.execute(q, (str(predstavnik_id), ))` (notice the tuple), where `str(predstavnik_id)` is the only element of that sequence.

The other function suffers from the same problem.

Python *should* raise a `RuntimeError` if those strings are not exactly 1 character, yet if your `id` values are small integers (< 10), it will Just Work (tm) without you noticing the bug.

Comment: Good catch. Additionally: you don't even need the call to `str`.

Comment: @Matthias, yes, or maybe no. The code in the question only allures to the fact that the parameters are integers. Also, converting to a string before passing the object to `execute` forces the parameter-binding to _not_ use any other converter. So it's not the same, and safer to just replicate what Op wrote, in order not to introduce subtle changes in behavior.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll try your solutions, but as i said, the first one working ok and returning rows from table "ulaz". The second one is the problem,  it does'nt raise the error but just return None []. empty ...

Comment: @zlocko, both functions as shown in the question are wrong in any case. As I said above, if `predstavnik_id` is a small integer, it will _seem_ to work, because `str(5)` is the same as `('5', )` when interpreted as a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys but it's nothing wrong with code.
It's all in my idiotic head.

I put some dummy data in db for testing, but i put it in wrong version.
Instead of db in my project, i referenced db (same name) in sqlite studio from older version of my project ...  :-)
Sorry for wasting your (&my) time

Happy new 2024